# Xps printer driver Filter

Tags: printing, xps

Now I want to filter print driver by interface `IPrintPipelineFilter` with Microsoft offered.there is an example in SDK src  `SimplePipelineFilter` `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\print\SimplePipelineFilter` . I can obtain the print content, add watermark or do other things with this filter frame. But I don't know how to filter all the `XPS` printers in windows. 
  I think out an idea modifying the config file like HP1100SD-pipelineconfig.xml or `xdsmpl-pipelineconfig.xml` , in folder `C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3` (my windows)  . Add a new item in it,  then the print driver(printfilterpipelinesvc.exe) can load my dll, and it works well for some printer drivers, but it does not exist in some other print driver, like Microsoft XPS Document Writer.
 How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

For XPS drivers it appears they keep their config in the DriverStore windows system folder. You should be able to see which pipeline config file in Print Server Properties in Devices and Printers:

[image]